# Replication in PgPool2

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

Anyone help me with this, I want to replicate postgresql data using pgpool in one Vm with other two Vm’s. I am new to this field I installed postgresql-9.3 in three Vm’s and pgpool-II in one Vm’s. Now I want to know how to replicate data between vm’s and What are the necessary changes in Pgpool.conf file, pool_hba.conf file and pcp.conf? What changes should I make in postgresql file like postgresql.conf & pg_hba.conf and where should I make these changes whether in primary node like in Vm I installed pgpool-II or in slave node other two Vm’s?

Please help me with this I am in confusing state and provide me good websites or tutorials to follow this?

Update see the config file - below

```
STANDBY SERVER
pg_hba.conf
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
#host   all             all         127.0.0.1/32            ident
# IPv6 local connections:
#host   all             all         ::1/128                 ident
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication    postgres                                peer
#host   replication     postgres    127.0.0.1/32            ident
#host   replication     postgres    ::1/128                 ident
# host  all         all         0.0.0.0.0               trust
  host  all         postgres    0.0.0.0.0               trust
#  host   all           all        primaryipaddress trust
 local  all         all                                 trust
 host   all         all            192.168.1.0/24   md5

postgresql.conf

listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                        # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                        # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                        # (change requires restart)
port = 5433
wal_level = hot_standby
#archive_command = '‘cp %p /var/lib/pgsql/wal_archive_27/%f'
max_wal_senders = 2 
hot_standby = on





Primary Server

pgpool.conf

# - pgpool Connection Settings -
 listen_addresses = '*'
socket_dir = '/var/ru
# - pgpool Communication Manager Connection Settings -
pcp_port = 9898
pcp_socket_dir = '/var/run'
# - Backend Connection Settings -
backend_hostname0 = 'xxxxxxx’'
backend_port0 = 5432
backend_weight0 = 1
backend_data_directory0 = '/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data'
backend_flag0 = 'ALLOW_TO_FAILOVER'
#backend_hostnamex1 = 'xxxxxxxx’
#backend_port1 = 5433
#backend_weight1 = 1
#backend_data_directory1 = '/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data'
#backend_flag1 = 'ALLOW_TO_FAILOVER'ckend_hostname1 = '3rd vm'
backend_hostname1 = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx’
backend_port1 = 5433
backend_weight1 = 1
backend_data_directory1 = '/var/lib/pgsql/9.3/data'
backend_flag1 = 'ALLOW_TO_FAILOVER'
# - What to log -
print_timestamp = on
log_connections = on
log_hostname = on
log_statement = on
log_per_node_statement = on
log_standby_delay = 'if_over_threshold'
# FILE LOCATIONS
pid_file_name = '/var/run/pgpool-II-93/pgpool.pid'
logdir = '/var/log/pgpool'
# REPLICATION MODE
replication_mode = on
replicate_select = on
# - Degenerate handling -
replication_stop_on_mismatch = on
# LOAD BALANCING
load_balance_mode = on
# HEALTH CHECK
health_check_user = 'apache'

pg_hba.conf

# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS        METHOD
host    all     all             0.0.0.0/0           md5
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                             trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         postgres        127.0.0.1/32        trust
# Allow any user from any host with IP address 192.168.93.x to connect
# to database "postgres" as the same user name that ident reports for
# the connection (typically the Unix user name).
#
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS        METHOD
host    postgres    all         xxxxxxxx    ident
# Allow a user from host 192.168.12.10 to connect to database
# "postgres" if the user's password is correctly supplied.
#
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS        METHOD
host    postgres    all         xxxxxxxxx   md5
host    all         postgres     xxxxxxxxxx         trust
#host   all         postgres        xxxxxxxxxx  trust

postgresql.conf
wal_level = hot_standby
#archive_mode = on
max_wal_senders = 2
hot_standby = on
log_statement = 'all'
```

Thanks in advance
Pal

Answer (score 0):

you can setup the PostgreSQL's native streaming replication for data replication among PG servers and configure pgpool-II on top of it. 
check out the following tutorial
http://www.pgpool.net/pgpool-web/contrib_docs/simple_sr_setting_3.1/

Comment: Thankyou for the link. But when I changed standby port# to 5433 and trying to run command psql but I got an error as below

[root@test3 data]# psql

psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Please Help me.

Comment: Are you trying to connect to standby server directly, without involving pgpool-II? If you can share your system setup details and configurations for pgpool-II and postgresql (pgpool.conf, postgresql.conf and pg_hba.conf), then it would be easier to identify the cause of this error.

Comment: Hi Muhammad, I added the code of my config files above in the question as a edit. please take a look . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent guide and hands-on guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvSzLjkMmQo. For the hands-on, go directly to 6:13.